# Выделение регуляркой имени из строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть строки с полным именем:

```
Sage, Miss. Dorothy Edith "Dolly"
Bystrom, Mrs. (Karolina)
Duran y More, Miss. Asuncion
```

Нужно выделить Имя из текста. Т.е Dorothy, Karolina, Asuncion.
Идея в том, что имя всегда идет после Mrs. или Miss.т.е. паттерн можно сделать на этом, но никак не получается до конца в синтаксисе разобраться. 
Прошу помочь написать работающий паттерн под задачу.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Регулярное выражение на [PHP](https://regex101.com/r/JVyyDK/1):

```
(?:Mrs.|Miss.)\s\(?\K\w+
```

Регулярное выражение на [JavaScript](https://regex101.com/r/JVyyDK/2):

```
(?<=(?:Mrs.|Miss.)\s\(?)\w+
```

Результат:

```
Match 1
Full match  12-19   `Dorothy`
Match 2
Full match  49-57   `Karolina`
Match 3
Full match  79-87   `Asuncion`
```

Comment: А для python? Прошу прощения что раньше не указал

Comment: @Gremlin, [вот тут посмотри](https://regex101.com/r/JVyyDK/3)